# Validation set after hyperparameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, validation

Let's say I'm comparing few models, and for my dataset I'm using train/validation/test split, and not cross validation. Let's say I'm completely done with parameter tuning for one of them and want to evaluate on the test set. Will I train a new model, on both the training and the validation datasets combined with the best configuration, or will I just run the same model on the test data?